# How to Set a Dropdowns Default Selection Based on the Logged in User

Tags: php, jquery, sql, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown control which and I would like it to default to a specific option based on the access of the logged in user. For example, the dropdown has 10 options but only administrators have access to view all 10 options. The majority of users only have access to 1 of the options though. The page contents are hidden/displayed based on whether or not the value of the dropdown is null.

**Question:** Using the example above, if an admin is logged in I need the dropdown to default to "Select an option". This way the page content is hidden. On the other hand, if a user with access to only 1 is logged in, I need it to default to that 1. This way they don't have to select anything and, by default the page content is displayed. How do I go about doing this?

Below is my current code which handles what the dropdown displays based on when a selection is made.

**PHP/HTML**

```
// Hide/Show main content div 
<?php
if (isset($_GET['src'])) {
    $src = $_GET['src'];
} else {
?>
<style>
#divmain { display: none; }
</style>
}
<?php } ?>

// Start of form, header, etc.
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<?php
$sql = getOptions();
$data = makeConnection($sql);
if ($src == null) {    // If value is null, default to 'Select an option'
    echo "<option selected value=\"\" disabled=\"disabled\">--Select an option--</option>";
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($db)) {
        echo "<option value=\"".$row['content']."\">".$row['content']."</option>";
    }
} else {    // If value not null keep the selected value selected
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($db)) {
        if ($row['content'] == $src) { $selected = " selected "; }
        else { $selected = " "; }
        echo "<option value=\"".$row['content']."\" ".$selected.">".$row['content']."</option>";
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
// Pass selected value on change
$('#select1').change(function() {
    var sel = $(this).val();
    location.href = "page1.php?src=" + sel;
}
```

**SQL**

```
// Hardcoding user for testing purposes, THIS WILL BE CHANGED
function getOptions() {
    $results = "SELECT content, userid FROM table WHERE userid = 'username'";

    return $results;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated and please let me know if I'm not clear about anything.

Comment: what problem you face on your code?

Comment: Right now, my dropdown is defaulting to "Select an option" no matter what access the user has. If the user only has access to one option, it should default to that option. If the user has access to more than one option, it should default to "Select an option".

Comment: You have a blank "selected" property in the "Select an option" part, this causes it to always be selected since it's the first to have a selected property.

Comment: @chenasraf I have that blank "selected" property because after the change fires and that value gets passed in, that selection will be maintained. If I don't have that, the dropdown will default to the first option after the change fires and the page is "reloaded". I know if I use ajax instead of posting that value, the page won't get reloaded but I'm trying to not have to rewrite a lot of code on many other pages. (I know now I should have done it that way to begin)

Comment: But it alwcays gets selected no matter what in that case. I suggest you use JS/jQuery to handle that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some help and have it figured out now. Here is the revised code:

**PHP/HTML**

```
// Hide/Show main content div 
<?php
$src = null;
if (isset($_GET['src'])) {
    $src = $_GET['src'];
} else {
?>
<style>
    #divmain { display: none; }
</style>
}
<?php } ?>

// Start of form, header, etc.
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<?php
$sql = getOptions();
$data = makeConnection($sql);
if ($src == null) {
    $i = 0;
    $content = "";
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($db)) {
        $content .= "<option value=\"".$row['content']."\">".$row['content']."</option>";
        $i++;
    }

    if ($i > 1) {
        echo "<option selected value=\"\" disabled=\"disabled\">--Select an option--</option>";
    }
    echo $content;

    if ($i > 1) { $oneopt = 1; }
    else { $oneopt = 0; }
} else {
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($db)) {
        if ($row['content'] == $src) { $selected = " selected "; }
        else { $selected = " "; }
        echo "<option value=\"".$row['content']."\" ".$selected.">".$row['content']."</option>";
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#select1').change(function() {
    var sel = $(this).val();
    location.href = "page1.php?src=" + sel;
}

<?php
    global $optone;
    if ($optone == 1) {
        echo "$('#select1').trigger('change');";
    }
?>
```

**SQL -- Stays the same**

@chenasraf really appreciate the help! Hope this can be of some help to someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

The preselected option is always the first to have a "selected" attribute. Your first disabled one has it first on all cases, so it's always chosen. Remove that and work from there.

On a side note, I think you can manage to make this options part work better. I've taken the liberty of rewriting it for you:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<?php
    $selected = '';
    while ($row = obdc_fetch_array($db)) {
        $options[] = '<option value="'.$row['content'].'">'.$row['content'].'</option>';
        if ($row['content'] == $src)
            $selected = count($options) - 1;
    }
    array_unshift($options, '<option disabled="disabled"', $selected == '' ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>--Select an option--</option>');

    foreach ($options as $option) {
        echo $option;
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Much appreciated but when I do this, it iterates through each one and adds "Select an option" every time it loops through. You are definitely correct about the issue being with the preselected option always being the first to have a selected attribute (or at least that's where I see my issue being). If the user only has access to 1 option and I could pass in that value when the page loads, $src wouldn't be null and it would go to my 'else' statement. If they have access to >1 option, nothing gets passed in and it works like it does now. Just thought about that but no clue how I can do it.